How to populate a "position" column (INT) based on existing rows?
MySQL 8.x
Given an existing table like this:



id
name
parent_fk
position (INT)




123
abc
1



124
def
1



125
xyz
2



126
ghi
1



127
def
2



128
abc
3




The (new) column position is supposed to logically represent each row's "position" as if the rows were in ordered collections grouped by parent_fk. I need a script that will populate that column. In other words: for each row, the value for position should be an increasing integer (starting at 0) that increments by 1 for each row, based on the value of `parent_fk'.
Here's an example desired end state. Actual "ordering" isn't really important as long as the values of position start at 0, increment by 1, and are unique for a given parent_fk.



id
name
parent_fk
position




12345
abc
1
0


12346
def
1
1


12347
xyz
2
0


12348
ghi
1
2


12349
def
2
1


12350
abc
3
0



I understand that rows in a table are not really "ordered" like an application might want/need, so please don't lecture me about that. This SQL change is needed to support an application that models the items as an ordered list. It's "good enough" to simply assign the position based on whatever order the rows are encountered during this migration script.

Feel free to ask clarification questions in the comments; I've tried to explain the need as concisely as possible, but if it needs the be better, let me know.

Just use a WINDOW function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

It looks like you need the RANK() window function.

The question this was marked as a duplicate of is significantly different - that one seeks to populate a column based only on grouping, with rows having the same value in 1 column all getting the identical value in the "derived" column. That's very different than what is being asked for here. DENSE_RANK() produces a very different result than ROW_NUMBER() which is what I'll use here.

@Barmar, I don't think so. If I'm understanding the documentation correctly, RANK() will have gaps (ties get the same value) which is definitely not what I need. I think I have a solution using ROW_NUMBER() as suggested by @NickW. Now if only someone hadn't prematurely closed the question as a duplicate, I could provide that solution as an answer...

I've reopened, but I'm sure there must be similar questions already.

I found one of them.

OK, but that question is over 15 years old and many of the answers are for obsolete versions of MySQL. This answer in particular is close to what is needed here. If I edit this to specify MySQL 8.x, could it be reopened long enough to provide the (very succint) answer using ROW_NUMBER and OVER?

I've changed the link to a different one that's more appropriate. There's milllions of these questions already, I don't think it's necessary to have another one saying the same thing. This is basically just ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_fk ORDER BY name) - 1

@E-Riz The dup I linked to has several answers using the window function.

@Charlieface fair enough, that one has the modern, simpler answer as the accepted answer.
